# google sign in Intent doesn't return RESULT_OK in start activity for result

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, google-signin, androidx

First I create a callback using New Api to get Activity for result

```
private val getGoogleDataBack=registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
  ActivityResultCallback {

      if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          Log.d(TAG, "------------------ACTIVITY START CALLBACK--------------------: ")
          val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(it.data)
          var userToken: String? = null

          try {
              var account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
              if (account != null) {
                  userToken = account.idToken
                  Log.d(TAG, "----------------------------$userToken: ")
              } else Log.d(TAG, "ACCOUNT IS NULL: ")
          } catch (e: Exception) {
              Log.d(TAG, ":FAILED TO GET USER ${e.message}")
          }

          viewModel.handleEvent(LoginEvent.OnGoogleSignInResult(LoginResult(123, userToken!!)))
      }
      else{
          Log.d(TAG, "------------------RESULT ISN'T OKAY ${it.resultCode}  ----------------: ")
      }
  })
```

and here's the google sign in code

```
private fun startSignInFlow() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startSignInFlow: ---------------START SIGN IN FLOW")
    val gso=GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.clientId))
        .build()
     val gSignInClient=GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireActivity(),gso)
      val signInIntent= gSignInClient.signInIntent
    getGoogleDataBack.launch(signInIntent)

}
```

Manifest

```
  <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It opens the google activity then I choose an Email but when activty for result callback get called it always enter the else where resultCode ISN'T OKAY can somebody help me?
logcat

```
 AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.noteapp, PID: 13979
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=860860250, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.noteapp/com.example.noteapp.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.noteapp.ui.AuthenticationFragment$getGoogleDataBack$1.onActivityResult(AuthenticationFragment.kt:49)
    at com.example.noteapp.ui.AuthenticationFragment$getGoogleDataBack$1.onActivityResult(AuthenticationFragment.kt:26)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:344)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:308)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:618)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Are you using any special launch mode for your `Activity`?

Comment: I am using the new API here    https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: Please edit your question and post the `<activity>` declaration from your manifest for the `Activity` that is registering for the activity result callback.

Comment: I am using a fragment

Comment: Your `Fragment` is hosted in an `Activity`. Please post the manifest declaration for that `Activity`.

Comment: I am using one activity with navigation component  I edited the post

Comment: Have you checked the logcat for any errors or exceptions? Don't filter the logcat or you may miss something important. It sounds like Android cannot (for whatever reason) deliver the result from the `Activity` you've launched back to your app. There should be some messages in logcat about why

Comment: for some reason it worked now but gave an exception I edited it

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace from the logcat so we know where the `NullPointerException` is coming from

Comment: I did ..it's because the use token is null I want to know why

Answer (score 1):

You will have a couple of OAuth_2.0 ids, the one which should be used is the **Web Client** auth Id. Secondly check if your app's SHA1/SHA256 is in firebase app fingerprints.

[image: IDs]